# What is the cause of rotted exterior wall framing behind concrete steps?

Tags: pest-control, water-damage

While demolishing front steps in our house we noticed moisture damage. Can someone help identify if this looks like termite damage?

[image]

There is also damage on the other side, but it doesn't look as severe.

[image]

What would be the best plan of action in situations?

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is either termites or carpenter ants. Likely water damaged wood made for easy eating.

Replace the badly damaged wood (i.e. repair the damage), treat for insects, and ensure the repair is water proofed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like plain ol' rot to me. It's what happens when someone plunks concrete against a house without proper flashing. Insect involvement is a symptom, not a cause.

You'll have to assess whether there's enough wood compromised to warrant repairs. If so, you'll need to temporarily remove some siding and open things up. Repairs this small can usually be done without worrying about jacking things up to support the roof or floors above. Cut out the damage, slide in new lumber, waterproof and close it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have termite service, you should.  They will know.  Termites leave signs they've been there.

Most likely, the wood rotted because it's open to rain.  Repair/replace and consider using a plastic product that won't rot again.